# Add files to entry, twice a week

Tags: ee2

I have a channel with entries
Every entry have only one field for file upload.
How to add second/3-rd/4 etc.. file into entry without adding fields for new files?
May be anyone know module?

Comment: Can you elaborate as to why you can't edit field groups? There are plenty of ways to do this, but not if you aren't allowed to by some administrator or site owner...

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend something like Matrix. You could have a single column Matrix field of file upload fields. But as for conversion of what you have? Forget it. To do what you want, you need to edit field groups, and it sounds like that isn't an option.

If it is, get Matrix, it's awesome.

https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/matrix

Answer (score 0):

Your easier option for it is to put the File field inside a [Grid](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/grid.html).

The first example on the user guide is about File fields.

Comment: Lol, sorry Robson, I'm spoiled by having University funding (and already available licenses). Matrix is still definitely better than the first party grid field (please correct me if I'm wrong!), but it sounds like this person can't change field groups, so the point is moot. Do you know of any methods around this? I thought of creating a new channel to act as a relationship field... but again, editing field groups!

Comment: You probably can code something to copy data from one table to another, but I'm not sure about it. Oh, and I always suggest a core solution first, before go after a third party one.